# Identifying a film where students take a drug that causes craving for blood

Tags: story-identification, movie

The basic premise is that someone rediscovers the formula for a drug that induces a state of ecstasy in the user. However, the side effect is that the user ends up craving blood.

I suspect I would have watched this around 2000-2002.

The scenes I remember (unfortunately):

- Several students are using the drug
- One of the female students has their drink spiked (I think it was a  glass of milk for some reason) with the drug by her "friends".
- She retires to bed and the drug kicks in, let's just say there's a fairly erotic scene where she umm..., "pleasures herself"...
- She wakes up with no real memory of where she has been and proceeds to vomit blood into the toilet.
- Because of ^^^ she goes to hospital to be checked out, and I believe that's when she realises she was drugged after a blood test.
- She then some how has flash backs of stopping someone in a jeep with his girlfriend, then feeding/killing (can't remember the exact details here).
- Somehow (I don't remember how) she tracks down the inventor of the original formula and he explains the effects and a couple of other bits.
- There's a scene towards the end (a rather blood filled one) where they're in a cabin somewhere and the same female student realises that another female friend she didn't think had taken the drug, actually had done - and that she's in real danger.

I've looked at http://themovieorphan.com/vampire-movies.html and it is not listed there.

Comment: I'd have answered it sooner except that I had the tag on ignore for a few hours.

Comment: @Richard Did you know that if you ever set a tag on ignore that you have a gold tag badge in, you automatically lose your dupehammer powers? ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor - I tend to set it to ignore while I'm working my way through the [unanswered questions](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This sounds like [SideFX](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0441821/) from 2005.

> Sex, drugs, and rock-and-roll will never be the same after a medieval
>   sex drug makes a comeback on the college party scene. Everyone wants
>   to try this "orgasm" drug but no one considers the side effects. This
>   drug took its first victims in 1646. The church soon discovered that
>   the blood-drained corpses found around the countryside were due to
>   strigol, an elixir that made select victims thirst for blood. The drug
>   wears off in hours, but while under its influence average men turn
>   into animals. The church destroyed much of the strigol, or the
>   vampire, but not all. And now, it's back. It's October 2004, and some
>   college students are throwing a party at an abandoned farm to
>   introduce their latest discovery, AYCE, a drug they promise is like
>   nothing else. The one person who knows the side effects arrives too
>   late. The bash becomes a bloodbath, and for the next few hours no one
>   knows who will become the next victim or the next vampire.

Comment: For the record, this film is dreck. Instead of watching it, you could use the time more usefully to get yourself a mani-pedi, learn to cook the perfect omelette or visit a local museum.

Comment: Completely agree. I was talking to a mate about really *beep* films and it came to mind - just couldn't remember the name. (I'd prefer a complete loss of memory regarding the whole thing - but  alas)

Comment: BTW - what search terms did you use for this?

Comment: @JonClements - [Movie AND ("sex drug" AND "vomits blood")]